# How to bind dynamically deserialized JSON with Expandoobject to XAML UI directly as property in Windows Phone 8

Tags: dynamic, binding, windows-phone, json.net

I am using JSON.net and what I want is to be able to directly bind dynamically deserialized JSON to be bindable as property in XAML directly without defining base classes for the JSON conversion. By it I mean run time binding and not compile type binding - to various elements straight away so as not require backcodding for each JSON file :

```
void LoadJsonfrmWeb(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            Stream stream = e.Result;

            dynamic json = new ExpandoObject();

            json = JsonHelpers.CreateFromJsonStream<ExpandoObject>(stream);
```

NOW: In UI I want to be able to do like this for following sample JSON:

```
{
     "id": "6",  
     "firstName": "Rose",
     "lastName": "Tobin",
     "age": 34,
     "address":
     {
         "streetAddress": "Butterfly Cresecent",
         "city": "Dublin",
         "state": "IR",
         "postalCode": "140085"
     },
     "phoneNumber":
      [   
         {
           "type": "home",
           "number": "001 990-0018"
         },
         {
           "type": "fax",
           "number": "124 999-9808"
         }
     ]

 }

<Grid x:Name="detail" DataContext="{Binding Path=json}">    
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=firstName.Value}"  />    
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=lastName.Value}" />
```

I have tried ImpromptuInterface, and exploring various options as DLR but not quite able to do it yet.. :(

Any Ideas, help or suggestion is deeply anticipated and it would be very nice if anyone can help me here  .. :)

Thank you all :)

Thanks ..

Comment: What's your datacontext? Did you tried to see bind just to 'firstname' without '.Value'? Do you have a repro sample? The part of code you show here gives too little information to help you. [How to ask, just in case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Phone 8 you can use a PropertySet.
Deserialize the JSON to a property set and you can bind directly to it.
Property sets can contain property sets so you can have complex objects without having to pre define them

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.collections.propertyset.aspx